# Different Valuse Returned from Using PCA Function

Tags: r, pca

Can someone explain to me how these are different?

```
#First Type of PCA.  Scales and Transposes manually
pr.data <- prcomp(scale(t(data)))

#Second Type of PCA
pr.data <- prcomp(data, retx=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
```

Is it simply that one is transposed (the first one) and the second one is not transposed?

Comment: `retx=TRUE` is already the default. And you scale in both cases. The only difference is whether you transpose the matrix or not (thus computing the PCA on different variables).

Comment: The eigenvectors of a transpose matrix are generally different from those of the original matrix. Therefore you can't expect to obtain the same results of a PCA for the two cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `t(data)` will definitely affect your data because you switch the positions of "samples vs. features" to "features vs. samples." Transposing the matrix will "flip" the analysis.